# Platform class java.util.Collections$SingletonMap (with no annotations) requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered

Tags: moshi

I have to create and pass Moshi a custom JsonAdapter for `java.util.Collections$SingletonMap` type, if I get the error message correctly. The problem is, that *SingletonMap* is private in 'Collections'.

```
val movies: MutableList<Movie> = Collections.synchronizedList(mutableListOf(
    Movie("Home alone"),
    Movie("Terminator"),
    Movie("Independence day")
))
// and later
get("/movies") {
     call.respond(mapOf("movies" to synchronized(movies) { movies.toList() }))
}
```

Here `mapOf()` returns `Map<String, List<Movie>>` and backed by `java.util.Collections.singletonMap(K key, V value)` which returns *SingletonMap*.

My attempt to implement JsonAdapter for Map. Didn't help though

```
    class MapJsonAdapter(
                private val elementAdapter: JsonAdapter<Any?>
            ) : JsonAdapter<Map<Any, Any?>>() {
            object Factory : JsonAdapter.Factory {
                override fun create(type: Type, annotations: Set<Annotation>,
                                    moshi: Moshi
                ): JsonAdapter<*>? {
                    if (annotations.isNotEmpty()) return null
                    val rawType = Types.getRawType(type)
                    if (rawType != Map::class.java) return null
                    val elementType = (type as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0]
                    return MapJsonAdapter(moshi.adapter(elementType))
                }
            }

            override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): Map<Any, Any?> {
                throw UnsupportedOperationException()
            }

            override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: Map<Any, Any?>?) {
                checkNotNull(value, { "Adapter doesn't support null. Wrap with nullSafe()." }).apply {
                    writer.beginObject()
                    value.forEach { t, u ->
                        elementAdapter.toJson(writer, t)
                        elementAdapter.toJson(writer, u)
                    }
                    writer.endObject()
                }
            }
        }

    // Usage in ktor
    //...
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
            moshi {
                add(MapJsonAdapter.Factory)
            }
        }
```

Any way to overcome the problem?

Comment: Got this one today too - thank you for posting it